# How to give cell reference in SQL connection string

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fetch Server and Database names from cells for establishing a connection to SQL server using excel macro as shown below-

so that I don't have to change it every time in my VB code.

[image: Image_of_Server and database name]

**ISSUE**

But the code which I have created is not taking values from the cells, it keeps on giving me unspecified error when I am trying to establish a connection between my excel sheet and SQL server using the cell values

In my code, I am trying to get server and database names from the cells of my sheet.
 please find the code value-

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     Worksheets(2).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POS DATA").Columns("B:B").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

        Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim iRowNo As Double
        Dim Server1 As String
        Dim DB1 As String


           Server1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import to SQL").Range("G5").Value
           DB1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import to SQL").Range("G7").Value


            conn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server='" & Server1 & "';Initial Catalog='" & DB1 & "' ;Trusted_Connection=yes;timeout=30;"

 conn.Close
 Set conn = Nothing

End sub
```

I am not able to figure this out, please help me regarding this.

Comment: I think that it's the single quotes in your connection string.  I've never seen a connection string that used single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
conn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=" & Server1 & ";Initial Catalog=" & DB1 & " ;Trusted_Connection=yes;timeout=30;"
```